# Are s3 prefixes deleted by the lifecycle management?

Tags: amazon-s3, lifecycle, prefix

Are (empty) prefixes also deleted by the s3 lifecycle management?

Answer (score 0):

S3 is a glorious hash table of (key, value) pairs. The presence of '/' in the key gives the illusion of folder structure and the S3 web UI also organizes the keys in a hierarchy. So, if lifecycle management rules end up deleting all the keys with a certain prefix, then it essentially means the prefix is also deleted (basically, there is no key with such a prefix). HTH.

Comment: Is there some documentation about that? I'm just confused, because it's possible to have empty prefixes. So are they treated as objects then?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html => "The Amazon S3 data model is a flat structure: you create a bucket, and the bucket stores objects. There is no hierarchy of subbuckets or subfolders." @ElGohr

Comment: I don't think that this applies to the lifecycle. Let's say I would create prefix a and put object b into a after a day. So the prefix would be deleted before the object?

Comment: could you please help me understand how you would "create a prefix 'a'"?@ElGohr

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/create-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: yes

More detail: prefix are just 0-byte object. When you use the Amazon S3 console to create a folder, Amazon S3 creates a 0-byte object with a key that's set to the folder name that you provided. For example, if you create a folder named photos in your bucket, the Amazon S3 console creates a 0-byte object with the key photos/. The console creates this object to support the idea of folders.[How S3 supports folder idea](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/UsingMetadata.html)